# Setting up target architecture on gcc to target SH2A

Tags: c, gcc

I've been struggling with how to get gcc to compile a single .c file for SuperH. I've searched through the documentation here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/SH-Options.html but every argument comes back with "gcc: error: unrecognized command line option". I just did the basic installation with MinGW (I'm running Windows), is there an additional package I need to install?

Comment: It might be useful to give more information about how you try to compile it, and your command line parameters.

Comment: You need to install aprorioate gcc, that supports compilation for this target. Ex. see [this](https://wiki.debian.org/SH4)

Comment: `gcc` doesn't support your target. `gcc-sh4-linux-gnu` does

Comment: currently i just use gcc -m2a-nofpu -c MyFileName.c. I will eventually add more arguments but i just want to see that it actually has the capability to compile.

@KamilCuk thanks, but it doesn't look like that will support SH2, just 3 and 4. I've looked around, seems like there's a couple builds for linux but none for windows that i've found. Might have to go that route

Comment: You have to build it yourself to use it. Easiest way for windows - install virtual machine with linux.